# Cannot assign value to checkbox in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am creating a list of check boxes via a result set. I can see the correct values but I am not able to set the value correctly

```
 <ul>
    <li v-for="role in roles">
        <input type="checkbox" :value="role.id"  v-model="form.roleIds" > {{role.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on one of the check boxes, I see all of them clicked.

[image]

That's what I see in console:

[image]

Comment: Whats `form.roleIds`?

Comment: `form: {
        file: null,
        name: null,
        description: null,
        url: null,
        position: null,
        partnerId: null,
        roleIds: null,
      },` that's the next step, you can see the html generated, there is no value being set @Vucko

Comment: It's null so every chechkbox is binding to that null. Use an array reather. Look at the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/boilerplate/vue) example how they bind the value to each object in the array.

Comment: @Vucko actually i wanted to show that form exists. I am not talking about server side now, I am getting the value as boolean instead of integer. Value is empty, you can see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your data property `roleIds` is not defined properly, it should be like this -

```
roleIds: []
```

> Test.vue

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(role, i) in roles" :key="i">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" :value="role.id"  v-model="form.roleIds" >
        {{role.name}}
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      form: {
        roleIds: [] // **this is the catch**
      },
      roles: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Siddharth'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Arora'
      }]
    })
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Console the `roles` array and confirm there is value for `id` in every entries of `roles`. It seems like the value for `id` is null.

Comment: You are right, there was a jsonignore tag on the property which is why json couldn't get it